# adding extensions to a certificate request ( password-challenge ) with C# and CertENrollLib

Tags: c#, smartcard, certenroll

I have to add extensions to a certificate request ( CSR ) in such a way that I respect a given structure. Namely this one[image: ASN .1 structure]

On the left is the structure I must respect for the chalenge password, on the right the structure I get when I simply generate  a OID object from the challenge-password OID value, then embedding all this directly into the extension list of the PKCS10 request:

```
CObjectId cp_oid = new CObjectId();

// OID 1.2.840.113549.1.9.7
// cp_oid.InitializeFromName(CERTENROLL_OBJECTID.XCN_OID_RSA_challengePwd);
cp_oid.InitializeFromValue("1.2.840.113549.1.9.7");
```

then I create a CX509Extension object add the OID to the PKCS10 request:

```
CX509Extension extension = new CX509Extension();
string b64__challengePassword=System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.challengePassword));

extension.Initialize(cp_oid, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY, b64__challengePassword);
_certificateRequest.X509Extensions.Add(extension);
```

since the structure is clearly different from what I must obtain ( see the right part of the previous picture ) , I am now using a more sophisticated approach:

```
_certificateRequest = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10();
_certificateRequest.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, (CX509PrivateKey)_privateKey, null);
_certificateRequest.Subject = (CX500DistinguishedName)_subjectName;

CObjectIds cp_oids = new CObjectIds();

CObjectId cp_oid = new CObjectId();
// OID 1.2.840.113549.1.9.7
// cp_oid.InitializeFromName(CERTENROLL_OBJECTID.XCN_OID_RSA_challengePwd);
cp_oid.InitializeFromValue("1.2.840.113549.1.9.7");

CX509Extension _extension = new CX509Extension();

cp_oids.Add(cp_oid);

//now how do I add that oid list to the 1.2.840.113549.1.9.14 OID ?
//I try with CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage instead of a simple CX509Extension
//which one of all these is the correct extensions?
/*
 *  IX509ExtensionAlternativeNames          Specifies one or more alternative name forms for the subject of a certificate.
    IX509ExtensionAuthorityKeyIdentifier    Represents an AuthorityKeyIdentifier extension.
    IX509ExtensionBasicConstraints          Specifies whether the certificate subject is a certification authority and, if so, the depth of the subordinate certification authority chain.
    IX509ExtensionCertificatePolicies        Represents a collection of policy information terms.
    IX509ExtensionMSApplicationPolicies     Represents a collection of object identifiers that indicate how a certificate can be used by an application.
    IX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage            Represents a collection of object identifiers that identify the intended uses of the public key contained in a certificate.
    IX509ExtensionKeyUsage                    Represents restrictions on the operations that can be performed by the public key contained in the certificate.
    IX509Extensions                         Manages a collection of IX509Extension objects.
    IX509ExtensionSmimeCapabilities            Represents a collection that reports the decryption capabilities of an email recipient to an email sender.
    IX509ExtensionSubjectKeyIdentifier        Represents a SubjectKeyIdentifier extension used to identify a signing certificate.
    IX509ExtensionTemplate                    Represents a CertificateTemplate extension that contains a version 2 template.
    IX509ExtensionTemplateName                Represents a CertificateTemplateName extension that contains a version 1 template.
                 */

CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
eku.InitializeEncode(cp_oids);
eku.Critical = false;

CX509AttributeExtensions InitExt = new CX509AttributeExtensions();

//  Add the extension objects into an IX509Extensions collection.
CX509Extensions ext1 = new CX509Extensions();
ext1.Add((CX509Extension)eku);
//  Use the IX509Extensions collection//to initialize an IX509AttributeExtensions object.
CX509AttributeExtensions ext1att = new CX509AttributeExtensions();
ext1att.InitializeEncode(ext1);

//Add the IX509AttributeExtensions object to an IX509Attributes collection.
CX509Attributes att1 = new CX509Attributes();
att1.Add((CX509Attribute)ext1att);

//Use the IX509Attributes collection to initialize an ICryptAttribute object.
CCryptAttribute crypt1 = new CCryptAttribute();
crypt1.InitializeFromValues(att1);

//Initialize a CMC or PKCS #10 request object and retrieve the ICryptAttributes collection.


//Add the ICryptAttribute object to the ICryptAttributes collection for the request.
_certificateRequest.CryptAttributes.Add(crypt1);

//Console.WriteLine("-- encode");
this.status2 = this.status2 + "-- encode <BR>";


try
{
    _certificateRequest.Encode();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}

string rawData = _certificateRequest.get_RawData();

Console.WriteLine("data=" + rawData);
```

However I get the puzzling error "The file exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070050)" at the end of the process when encoding the request , I tried with different smartcards ad the key containers are OK, not full.

Is my approach toward adding this challenge-password extension correct and how can I interpret this error?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the error you are getting "The file exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070050)" is because trying to set a key on a template that already has a key. just comment this:

```
    CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
    eku.InitializeEncode(cp_oids);
    eku.Critical = false;

    CX509AttributeExtensions InitExt = new CX509AttributeExtensions();


  //  Add the extension objects into an IX509Extensions collection.
    CX509Extensions ext1= new CX509Extensions();
    ext1.Add((CX509Extension)eku);
```

and it should work.

---

search for this in the in the article [Working with Active Directory Certificate Service via C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2012/01/13/working-with-active-directory-certificate-service-via-c.aspx) for:

> Seems that we finished, but if we just execute it will throw an
>   exception to us, said that the file exists when adding some
>   extensions.

it explains everything.

---

from the article:

> The exception message could be a little bit confusing. In fact this is
>   because we defined something which had been defined in the certificate
>   template. If we dig into the source code we can see that the exception
>   occurred when we added the key usage extension.
>
> And if we get back to the CA server and open the template we are
>   using, we can find that the key usage had been defined in the
>   template. This means in the code, or in the certificate request we
>   should not specify it again.
>
> Hence we need to comment the code for adding the key usage, also we
>   need to comment the enhanced key usage part since it had been defined
>   in the template, too. Because we let the request supply the subject
>   name so here we can still specify the subject information in the
>   request. The method for generating request message would be like this.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code to include Challenge Password into PKCS10 generated by CertEnroll:

```
private static byte[] getDerBytes(int tag, byte[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length > byte.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Support for integers greater than 255 not yet implemented.");
        }

        var header = new byte[] { (byte)tag, (byte)data.Length };
        return header.Concat(data).ToArray();
    }
```

and

```
public static byte[] EncodePrintableString(string data)
    {
        var dataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        return getDerBytes(0x13, dataBytes);
    }
```

and finnally:

```
CObjectId cp_oid = new CObjectId();

                cp_oid.InitializeFromName(CERTENROLL_OBJECTID.XCN_OID_RSA_challengePwd);
                byte[] b64__challengePassword = EncodePrintableString("password");

                ICryptAttribute ChallengeAttributes = new CCryptAttribute();
                ChallengeAttributes.InitializeFromObjectId(cp_oid);

                CX509Attribute ChallengeAttribute = new CX509Attribute();
                ChallengeAttribute.Initialize(cp_oid, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY, 
                                                    Convert.ToBase64String(b64__challengePassword));
                ChallengeAttributes.Values.Add(ChallengeAttribute);

                objPkcs10.CryptAttributes.Add((CCryptAttribute)ChallengeAttributes);
```